# How to subtract a number from a string in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of numbers as:

input    `P[i] = int(mycsv[i][5]) # Obtaining my string "P" including 10 int values`

output    `{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 2, 10: 5}`

input     `d = int(mycsv[1][10]) # Obtaining my number "1", even though it is trivial`

output    `1`

I just need to create another string named "`c_i`". It should be this simple:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    c_i[i] = P[i] - d
```

However, this is not working. Apparently, Python is much weird than Matlab. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In python, you can't edit an existing string, you have to either append to it or make a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the string first. Try

```
c_i = ""
for i in range(1,11):
    c_i += P[i] - d
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used:
`c_i = {}`
`for i in range(1,11):`
`c_i[i] = P[i] - d`
and it worked. Thank you very much for reminding to create the string first. What is the difference between `" "` and `{}`?

Comment: Glad to help! "" is a string value, {} is a dictionary. A dictionary is essentially python's equivalent of a HashMap, which by default uses integers as keys starting a 0.